# How to read the JSON API HEADER for android app?

Tags: android, json, rest

In my android app, there is login feature. I believe the the authentication process is done at the server end. My API developer is saying that I have to read the API HEADER STATUS to know if user has successfully logged in or not? Something like REST STATUS()....if response is 200, it means success. There is no custom field for response in the api.

But I don't know how to read this header status?

My api is - rajeshrolen-001-site1.smarterasp.net/api/user

Please help.

Comment: u want to read header in php?

Comment: no, The API is in .NET